# Resizing rows in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Simply put, I am trying to add labels dynamically into a TableLayoutPanel that can be invisible and, in that case, setting the height to 0 to avoid awkward empty rows.

(I need this to work like an accordion, and I am using a TableLayout because later I will need to use complex controls such as treeViews):

```
while index < myDataTable.rows.count
    dim myLabel as new Label
    myLabel.Name = myDataTable.rows(index)("labelText").toString
    myLabel.Text = myDataTable.rows(index)("labelText").toString

    myTableLayout.controls.Add(myLabel, 0, index)

    If cbool(row("initialyVisible")) then
        myTableLayout.GetControlFromPosition(0, index).Visible = true
        myTableLayout.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150))
    else
        myTableLayout.GetControlFromPosition(0, index).Visible = false
        myTableLayout.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 0))
    endif
    index = index + 1
end while
```

This works well.

However, during the execution, the visible status of these labels + rows height might change:

```
If visibleFlag = true Then
   myTableLayout.RowStyles(i).Height = 150
   myTableLayout.GetControlFromPosition(0, i).Visible = True
Else
   myTableLayout.RowStyles(i).Height = 0
   myTableLayout.GetControlFromPosition(0, i).Visible = false
End If
```

Causing the 2 problems illustrated
[in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayPQe.png).
Anything that can be done?

Comment: Why not try [Removing a specific Row in TableLayoutPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15535214/719186)

Comment: You mean removing a specific row only to add it later again? Each of this hidden rows may very well need to be shown, depending on conditions.

Comment: If all you are showing are labels, then a DataGridView control might be a better choice.  The TableLayoutPanel control has some weird quirks.